# How can I get the content type for which a certain comment belongs?

Tags: 8

I have a comment type that's associated to various content types.

I have the comment entity but I want to get which content type(s) it belongs to.

How can I do that? Given that I can in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Comment::getCommentedEntity()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21comment%21src%21Entity%21Comment.php/function/Comment%3A%3AgetCommentedEntity/8.5.x) to get the entity, and if it's a node, grab the type:

```
$entity = $comment->getCommentedEntity();
if ($entity instanceof \Drupal\node\Entity\Node) {
  $type = $entity->getType();
}
```

Comment: Yeah D8 is a dream compared to D7 and before - there are so many convenience methods to make life easier